# Nav Bar not working properly-Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, web-applications

I have created a base.html in my Django project from which I inherit rest of the html pages. In my base.html I have created a nav bar that displays Home,About,Contact and [Myprofile and Logout] if the user is logged in else it shows [Register]. 
The problem is when I am logged in at my homepage I do see the button [Myprofile], but when I visit contact or About page, the [Myprofile] nav bar button is missing but [Logout] is working all fine.

Here is my base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>
    {% block title %}
     WEB PAGE BY SHASHANK
    {% endblock title %}
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />

</head>
<body>
        <div id="page">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href="/" id="logoLink">S PORTAL</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
             {% for thing in things %}
                {% if user == thing.user %}
                  <li><a href="{% url 'thing_detail' slug=thing.slug %}">My Profile</a></li>
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}


        {% else %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Login</a></li>

        <li><a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
        </div>


        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}


        <div id="footer">
            <p>
        Webpage made by <a href="/" target="_blank">SHASHANK</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

About.html

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% block title %} ABOUT - {{ block.super }}{% endblock title %}



{% block content %}

<h1>WHAT WE DO</h1>

<div id="content">
            <h2>ABOUT</h2>
            <p>
                We are a new software development company.
            </p>
      <p>We are trying to change the world and expecting to getting paid for the same</p>
            <p>
            Visit us on our <a href="www.facebook.com"> Facebook </a> page.
            </p>
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Urls.py

```
from collection.backends import MyRegistrationView
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from collection import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    password_reset,
    password_reset_done,
    password_reset_confirm,
    password_reset_complete
    )

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),

   url(r'^about/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'),name='about'),

   url(r'^contact/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html'),name='contact'),

   url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','collection.views.thing_detail',name='thing_detail'),

   url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$','collection.views.edit_thing',name='edit_thing'),

   url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/weight$','collection.views.edit_weight',name='edit_weight'),

   url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete/weight$','collection.views.remove_weight',name='remove_weight'),

   #WORKING url(r'^things/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', 'collection.views.remove_weight', name='remove_weight'),

   url(r'^things/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='weight_removed.html'),name='weight_removed'),

   url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$','collection.views.remove_weight',name='remove_weight'),






   #url(r'^edit/(?P<slug>\d+)/weights$', 'collection.views.AddWeight',name='AddWeight'),
   # the new password reset URLs
   url(r'^accounts/password/reset/$',password_reset,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_form.html'},name="password_reset"),
   url(r'^accounts/password/reset/done/$',password_reset_done,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_done.html'},name="password_reset_done"),
   url(r'^accounts/password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',password_reset_confirm,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_confirm.html'},name="password_reset_confirm"),
   url(r'^accounts/password/done/$',password_reset_complete,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_complete.html'},name="password_reset_complete"),


   #setup additional registeration page
   url(r'^accounts/register/$',MyRegistrationView.as_view(),name='registration_register'),
   url(r'^accounts/create_thing/$','collection.views.create_thing',name='registration_create_thing'),

   url(r'^accounts/',include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),


 ]
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from collection.models import Thing, Weight
from collection.forms import ThingForm, WeightForm, ThingWeightFormSet
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from django import forms

def index(request):
    things = Thing.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'things':things,})

def thing_detail(request, slug):
    # grab the object...
    thingRA = Thing.objects.get(slug=slug)
    weights = thingRA.weights.all().order_by('-date')
    # and pass to the template
    return render(request, 'things/thing_detail.html', {'thing': thingRA, 'weights':weights,})

def edit_thing(request, slug):
    # grab the object
    thing = Thing.objects.get(slug=slug)
    # set the form we're using
    form_class = ThingForm

    # if we're coming to this view from a submitted form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # grab the data from the submitted form and apply to
        # the form
        form = form_class(data=request.POST, instance=thing)
        if form.is_valid():
            # save the new data
            form.save()
            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
# otherwise just create the form
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=thing)

# and render the template
    return render(request, 'things/edit_thing.html', {'thing': thing,'form': form,})

def create_thing(request):
    form_class = ThingForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            thing = form.save(commit=False)
            thing.user = request.user
            thing.slug = slugify(thing.name)
            thing.save()
            slug = slugify(thing.name)
            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
    else:
        form = form_class()

    return render(request,'things/create_thing.html', {'form': form,})


def edit_weight(request, slug):
    thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = WeightForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            weight = form.save(commit=False)
            weight.thingRA = thing
            weight.save()
            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
    else:
        form = WeightForm()
    return render(request, 'things/edit_weight.html', {'form': form})

"""WORKING WEIGHT
def remove_weight(request, pk):
            weight = get_object_or_404(Weight, pk=pk)
            thing_pk = weight.thingRA.pk
            weight.delete()
            return redirect('weight_removed')
"""


def remove_weight(request, pk, slug):
            weight = get_object_or_404(Weight, pk=pk)
            thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, slug=slug)
            thing_pk = weight.thingRA.pk
            weight.delete()
            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=slug)


@login_required
def edit_thing(request, slug):
    # grab the object...
    thing = Thing.objects.get(slug=slug)
    # make sure the logged in user is the owner of the thing
    if thing.user != request.user:
        raise Http404
        # set the form we're using...
    form_class = ThingForm
    # if we're coming to this view from a submitted form,
    if request.method == 'POST':
         # grab the data from the submitted form and
         # apply to the form
         form = form_class(data=request.POST, instance=thing)
         if form.is_valid():
             # save the new data
             form.save()
             return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
    # otherwise just create the form
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=thing)
        # and render the template
    return render(request, 'things/edit_thing.html', {'thing': thing,'form': form,})
```

Comment: you should add your urls.py and the actual rendered page too not the template only

Comment: When you are rendering the `about` page, I think you forgot to pass the `things` parameter from the server side.

Comment: @maazza I added the URLs.py

Comment: @DivakarDass Sorry, I didnt understand (I have just started Django). But my base.html has all the nav bar info. I believe the contents of about.html will be just pushed between {% block content %}{% endblock content %}. Do I need pass anything explicitly?

Comment: can you repost the generated about page ? the urls seemed correct, you sur this is not a css issue do you have a screenshot ?

Comment: can you show us how the "things" are  generated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your my profile depends on a context variable called `things` which must be present in your homepage but nothing else. I'd imagine you only have one thing per user so you either need to just use that or take the first

```
 {% for thing in things %}
    {% if user == thing.user %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'thing_detail' slug=thing.slug %}">My Profile</a></li>
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

should be one of the following:

- Thing has a Many-to-one relationship with user

  ```
  <li><a href="{% url 'thing_detail' slug=user.thing_set.first.slug %}">My Profile</a></li>
  ```
- Thing has a one-to-one relationship with user

  ```
  <li><a href="{% url 'thing_detail' slug=user.thing.slug %}">My Profile</a></li>
  ```

Comment: right but maybe "thing_set" is not the related name

Comment: @maazza - `_set` is a django thing to find a many relationship ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)), if the op does have a related name then they can use that.

Comment: of course just pointing out we may need the definition of his models